# Is there any advantage setting OpenBSD as Domain Controller instead a Windows 2008?

Tags: domain-controller, openbsd

I have an OpenBSD 4.6 installation with LDAP ports configured correctly. I can create users and other objects. But, I'm a Windows user and I know how easy is create and configure a domain controller.

Comparing two systems, what is the best to set a Domain Controller in terms of management and performance?

This question is just to learn how OpenBSD works and not to get a production environment immediatly. I created some virtual machines, one with OpenBSD installed, and want to get some services as DC, mail server, ftp server, etc.
My intention is to know how BSD systems works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For managing Linux clients OpenBSD will be best.
For managing Windows clients, Windows will be best (and in my experience a lot lot better!).  Essentially you can forget anything other than the most basic NT4 style domain policies.

Your BSD server can be used as a backup DC see [the Samba HOWTO](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html#domain-member-server) for more info.  Although you may have to have a lower functional level of your forest/domain - see the Samba pages again.

Comment: So, what you are saying is Windows is better and OpenBSD will be as a backup. But, why use OpenBSD as a backup if you can have another Windows???

The link is very heplful. Thanks for it.

Comment: Well the only reason for using the BSD server is for you to learn from?

Comment: At this moment yes. I want to learn how to manage BSD servers. In a closer future, I hope to change my job using my new skills.

Comment: @jaloplo An OpenBSD license is... free? A Windows Server license is a bit more. So if you're pinching pennies, that's a motivation.

Answer (score 2):

If management and performance (and don't forget availability, reliability and predictable behaviour) are your priorities then stick with the one you know; especially if you have other users connecting to it who are depending on it for service.  From what you say it looks as though a Windows DC would pretty much fade into the background, whereas an OpenBSD one would require constant vigilance.  Do you want that on a live network?

Otherwise, by all means set up the OpenBSD based network on a few VMs and use that for learning.

Comment: My intention is getting some virtual machines with OpenBSD and others OS and how to connect them. As I write on the question (after update it) I just want learn how BSD systems works.

Answer (score 0):

For something this critical, you should go with what you know best. You don't want to learn OpenBSD while under severe pressure to restore a Domain Controller.

Comment: Despite of all my life I'm working under Windows OS but I want to learn OpenBSD as hobby or, in a future, can change my job.

Comment: I salute your eagerness, but a production Domain Controller is no place to do your learning.